# Date picker not working in Internet Explorer due to inability to convert strings to numbers

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer

I am making a date-filter that takes an input string using https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker formatted as such "MM/DD/YYYY" then attempting to convert that to a number to use it in a conditional which will conditionally show items that fall w/in the specified date.  My function takes undefined/NaNs and fills in Date.parse("01/01/1970") or Date.parse("01/01/3000") depending on start or end date.  My problem is that in IE all of my dates are returning NaN so the filter wont work - it works fine in Chrome and Edge, but does nothing in IE (since everything falls between 1971 and 3000.

I've tried slicing and dicing the data up a bunch of different ways, but it seems I can't even convert "10" to 10 in ie w/o getting NaN.

```
var isd: any = startDate[0].value;
        console.log(isd);
        console.log(typeof isd);
        var parts = isd.split("/");
        console.log(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);

        let year = parts[2];
        let month = parts[0]; // 0 is january
        let day = parts[1];
        console.log(year, month, day);
        console.log(typeof year, typeof month, typeof day)

        year = parseInt(year);
        month = parseInt(month) - 1;
        day = parseInt(day);
        console.log(year, month, day);

        let year2 = parts[2];
        let month2 = parts[0]; // 0 is january
        let day2 = parts[1];

        year2 = parseFloat(year2);
        month2 = parseFloat(month2) - 1;
        day2 = parseFloat(day2);
        console.log(year2, month2, day2);

        let year3 = parts[2];
        let month3 = parts[0]; // 0 is january
        let day3 = parts[1];

        year3 = Number(year3);
        month3 = Number(month3) - 1;
        day3 = Number(day3);
        console.log(year3, month3, day3);

        var inputStartDate: any = new Date(year, month, day);
        inputStartDate = inputStartDate.toString();

        // console.log(this.startDate, this.endDate, thisStartDate, thisEndDate);
        console.log(isd, ied, inputStartDate, inputEndDate);
```

I expect that when I do Number||parseInt||parseFloat("10") to get 10 back. but instead I get only NaN.

my console.log looks like:

```
10/10/2019
string
10 10 2019
2019 10 10
string string string
NaN NaN NaN (x3 lines)
‎10‎/‎16‎/‎2019  Invalid Date NaN
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's more, if I do Date.parse on the objects I'm comparing, it works w/o any interference:
`console.log(this.startDate); // 10/7/2019`
`const thisStartDate = Date.parse(this.startDate);`
`console.log(thisStartDate); // 1570420800000`

Comment: the dynamic ied (populated by a $("#inputField")[0].value;) is the same code, but results in NaN:
`console.log(ied); // 11/12/2019` - typeOf string
 `const anotherExperimentalStartDate = Date.parse(ied);`
`console.log(anotherExperimentalStartDate); // NaN`

Comment: I still don't know the answer to why I couldn't grab the date string from the input and use it - but I found a workaround in the onSelect option of my datepicker - the function has access to the instance dateSelected date obj and I just set that equal to a global var and worked with that instead - I think it is a better solution anyway.

Comment: It seems that you have found the solution of the issue. You could post the solution of the issue as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here's how I worked around this issue:

in the documentation, js-datepicker has an onSelect method which has access to that instance of datepicker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker#onselect) - the datepicker instance has a dateSelected attribute which is either undefined (no date selected) or a Date object matching the user selection.  I just set this dateSelected equal to a more globally scoped var (inputStartDate and inputEndDate) and used inputStart/EndDate.getTime() in my conditionals.  I also handled the null dates by setting them as either much earlier or later than the period the objects I was filtering against would be in.  Here's an example of my onSelect Code:

```
    onSelect: (instance: any) => {
        if (instance.el.id === "filter-start-date") {
            if (instance.dateSelected === undefined) {
                inputStartDate = new Date("05-02-91");
                // console.log("happy birthday!");
            } else {
                inputStartDate = instance.dateSelected; // date obj
            }
        } else if (instance.el.id === "filter-end-date") {
            if (instance.dateSelected === undefined) {
                inputEndDate = new Date("01-01-3031");
                // console.log("welcome to the future");
            } else {
                inputEndDate = instance.dateSelected;
            }
        }
```

This solution circumvented the whole process of grabbing data from the input field set by the datepicker which was somehow incompatible with selector methods/dom tree gettting/setting/data manipulation.